# How to define a new font family without specifying a font in advance (using the default one instead)?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, documentclass-writing, luaotfload

I want to setup a semantic font family for my class with `\newfontfamily\COMPONENTFont{XXX}`.

Users of the class are free to use their font of choice for COMPONENT, for instance font YYY: `\renewfontfamily\COMPONENTFont{YYY}`

However, I would like to avoid mentioning the specific font XXX, and letting fontspec load the default font, which probably is Latin Modern Roman.

However, with the following MWE I get errors with LuaLaTex and XeLaTeX:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% both seem to set "lmr"
% but it cannot be read by luaotfload because it is not in otf, ttf or ttc format
% adding a \setmainfont{Fira Code} works because the macro returns "FiraCode(0)"
\makeatletter
\newfontfamily\COMPONENTFont{\f@family}
%\newfontfamily\COMPONENTFont{\rmdefault}
\makeatother

\titleformat{name=\section}{\LARGE\COMPONENTFont\scshape}{}{0mm}{\thesection\ }

\begin{document}
\section{Section with cool font}

Paragraph with boring font

% users can modify this
%\setmainfont{Comic Sans}
%\renewfontfamily\COMPONENTFont{Chiller}

\end{document}
```

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
 L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty)
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: Font "lmr" not found.
luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.

! Package fontspec Error: The font "lmr" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 \makeatother
              
?
```

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm lmr
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input lmr
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf lmr
! I can't find file `lmr'.
<*> ...e:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input lmr
                                                  
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...e:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input lmr
                                                  
Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: lmr.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input lmr' failed to make lmr.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.


! Package fontspec Error: The font "lmr" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.11 \makeatother
                 
?
```

Comment: `\newfontfamily` expects the name of the font or a filename. It does not expect the name of a font family. `lmr` is the name of (a) font family, but that's no good here. How exactly are users to specify the variable component? Why do you want `\newfontfamily` here? Why not set `\newfontfamily` to the default and then use `\renewfontfamily` if the user specifies something?

Comment: See page 16 of the `fontspec` manual (sec 4.2) for a mechanism to do what you want, but the alternative later in the manual is apparently preferred. Note that you can't select a font with `\f@fontfamily` in NFSS either.

Comment: Do you want the default to be Latin Modern Roman? Or do you want it to be whatever font family is default at the start of the document? Or whatever is default when it is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `\COMPONENTFont` in the class or package file to mean the same as `\normalfont` and instruct users that they can do either

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\COMPONENTfont}{}{<some code>}
```

or

```
\renewfontfamily{\COMPONENTFont}{<font name>}[<options>]
```

##### Example 1, no user setting

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%%% ---------------------------------------------- %%%
%%% this would go in the class or package file
\NewDocumentCommand{\COMPONENTFont}{}{\normalfont}

\titleformat{name=\section}
  {\LARGE\COMPONENTFont\scshape}
  {}
  {0mm}
  {\thesection\ }

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\LARGE\COMPONENTFont\scshape}
  {}
  {0mm}
  {}
%%% end of class or package code
%%% ---------------------------------------------- %%%

% User code in the document

\begin{document}

\section*{Numberless section}

Some text

\section{Section with cool font}

Paragraph with boring font

\end{document}
```

[image]

##### Example 2, with `\renewfontfamily` and `\setmainfont`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%%% ---------------------------------------------- %%%
%%% this would go in the class or package file
\NewDocumentCommand{\COMPONENTFont}{}{\normalfont}

\titleformat{name=\section}
  {\LARGE\COMPONENTFont\scshape}
  {}
  {0mm}
  {\thesection\ }

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\LARGE\COMPONENTFont\scshape}
  {}
  {0mm}
  {}
%%% end of class or package code
%%% ---------------------------------------------- %%%

% User code in the document

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\renewfontfamily{\COMPONENTFont}{Source Sans Pro}

\begin{document}

\section*{Numberless section}

Some text

\section{Section with cool font}

Paragraph with boring font

\end{document}
```

[image]

##### Example 3, with `\RenewDocumentCommand`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%%% ---------------------------------------------- %%%
%%% this would go in the class or package file
\NewDocumentCommand{\COMPONENTFont}{}{\normalfont}

\titleformat{name=\section}
  {\LARGE\COMPONENTFont\scshape}
  {}
  {0mm}
  {\thesection\ }

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\LARGE\COMPONENTFont\scshape}
  {}
  {0mm}
  {}
%%% end of class or package code
%%% ---------------------------------------------- %%%

% User code in the document

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\COMPONENTFont}{}{\normalfont\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\section*{Numberless section}

Some text

\section{Section with cool font}

Paragraph with boring font

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this approach, `\NewDocumentCommand{\COMPONENTFont}{}{\normalfont}` is just one line and the user can still use `\renewfontfamily`

Answer (score 1):

The NFSS family name provided by `\f@family` can not be passed directly to fontspec since since it is not be the font filename and even when it is it is missing font features which can be important for many fonts.

`\renewfontfamily` does not just allow to redefine familes defined by `\newfontfamily` though but arbitrary commands, so you can define the default directly as a document command, e.g. using

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% This picks up the currently active family and encoding
\makeatletter
\expanded {%
  \NewDocumentCommand \noexpand \COMPONENTFont {}{%
    \noexpand \fontfamily {\f@family}%
    \noexpand \fontencoding {\f@encoding}%
    \noexpand \selectfont
  }%
}
\makeatother

\titleformat{name=\section}{\LARGE\COMPONENTFont\scshape}{}{0mm}{\thesection\ }

\begin{document}
\section{Section with cool font}

Paragraph with boring font

% users can modify this
%\setmainfont{Comic Sans}
%\renewfontfamily\COMPONENTFont{Chiller}

\end{document}
```